# Why is the norm map dual to restriction under Tate local duality?

Tags: abelian-varieties, duality, local-fields

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension of nonarchimedean local fields, and let $A$ and $A^t$ be dual abelian varieties over $K$. Tate local duality tells us that $A^t(K)$ and $H^1(K, A)$ are Pontryagin dual locally compact Hausdorff abelian topological groups, and likewise over $L$. Under this duality, why does the dual of the restriction map $H^1(K, A) \rightarrow H^1(L, A)$ identify with the norm map $A^t(L) \rightarrow A^t(K)$?

I am aware that this is "well-known" and that there are references that treat special cases, but I am interested in a proof or a reference in the stated generality.

Edit: Since $K$ is *any* nonarchimedean local field, the Tate local duality pairing $A^t(K) \times H^1(K, A) \rightarrow H^2(K, \mathbb{G}_m)$ that I am using is defined using biextensions (as in III.7 of Milne's Arithmetic Duality Theorems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note first of all that the "norm" map you speak of does not make sense unless the field extension is separable.  That is, for a separable field extension $k'/k$ of finite degree and a commutative $k$-group scheme $C$ there is a canonical "norm" homomorphism $C(k') \rightarrow C(k)$ induced by the passage to Galois-invariants on the homomorphism $C(k' \otimes_k k_s) \rightarrow C(k_s)$ arising from the canonical $k_s$-algebra decomposition of $k' \otimes_k k_s$ as a product of copies of $k_s$ indexed by ${\rm{Hom}}_k(k',k_s)$.  The same method defines a "norm" homomorphism $C(k' \otimes_k S) \rightarrow C(S)$ for any $k$-algebra $S$, so it corresponds to a natural $k$-homomorphism ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}(C_{k'}) \rightarrow C$ in terms of the Weil restriction when $C$ is finite type. This generalizes to when $k'/k$ is replaced with a finite etale cover. But beyond the separable setting there is no "reasonable" norm through finite flat maps whose formation commutes with base change.)  So for this reason, we are going to assume that $L/K$ is separable.

First, by the relationship between cup products and connecting homomorphisms (and the identification of $A^t(K)$ with ${\rm{Ext}}^1_K(A, \mathbf{G}_m)$ *functorially* in $A$) we see that the pairing $$A^t(K) \times {\rm{H}}^1(K,A) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^2(K, \mathbf{G}_m) = \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$$ 
identifies covariant functoriality in degree-1 cohomology as adjoint to dual-functoriality of abelian varieties.

Let $B$ denote the Weil restriction of scalars ${\rm{R}}_{L/K}(A_L)$; this is an abelian variety precisely because $L/K$ is separable. (If $L/K$ is not separable then $B$ is a smooth connected commutative $K$-group of dimension $[L:K]\dim(A)$ but is always non-proper if $A \ne 0$.) Let $j:A \rightarrow B$ be the natural inclusion.  Ultimately we are going to transform your question into the above functoriality of the Tate pairing over $K$ applied to the $K$-homomorphism $j$.

By Shapiro's Lemma considerations, we naturally identify ${\rm{H}}^i(L,A)$ with ${\rm{H}}^i(K,B)$, and (check!) this identifies the restriction map on ${\rm{H}}^1$'s with ${\rm{H}}^1(j)$.  Likewise, by the compatibility of Weil restriction with the formation of dual abelian variety (using the "norm" of the Weil restriction of the Poincare bundle), the norm map $A^t(L)\rightarrow A^t(K)$ is identified with the map on $K$-points induced by the dual homomorphism $j^t:B^t \rightarrow A^t$.  Also, and most crucially, by a bit of diagram chasing (using the role of "norm of Poincare bundle" above) we see that the Tate pairing for $B$ over $K$ is identified with the composition of the Tate pairing for $A_L$ over $L$ and the "norm" map on Brauer groups $${\rm{Br}}(L) = {\rm{H}}^2(L, \mathbf{G}_m) =
{\rm{H}}^2(K, {\rm{R}}_{L/K}(\mathbf{G}_m))\rightarrow {\rm{H}}^2(K,\mathbf{G}_m)={\rm{Br}}(K).$$
But when these flanking Brauer groups are identified with $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$, this composite map is the *identity*, as we see by analyzing pre-composition with the surjective restriction ${\rm{Br}}(K) \rightarrow {\rm{Br}}(L)$ (that intertwines with $[L:K]$ on $\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z}$ via local class field theory, and the composition of $\mathbf{G}_m \rightarrow {\rm{R}}_{L/K}(\mathbf{G}_m)$ with the "norm" map ${\rm{R}}_{L/K}(\mathbf{G}_m) \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m$ is $t \mapsto t^{[L:K]}$).

So putting it all together, the diagram you want to commute for $L/K$ separable really does translate into the elementary functoriality of the Tate pairing over $K$, applied to the map $j$ between abelian varieties over $K$.

---

Remark: In case $L/K$ is inseparable there is still something one might wish to prove.  Namely, focusing on the case when $L/K$ is purely inseparable of degree $p^n$ with $p = {\rm{char}}(K)>0$, so $L = K^{1/p^n}$ over $K$, we use the $p^n$-power isomorphism of local fields $L \simeq K$ to identify $A^t(L)$ with $(A^t)^{(p^n)}(K) = (A^{(p^n)})^t(K)$, so we could *define* the norm $A^t(L) \rightarrow A^t(K)$ to be the map on $K$-points induced by the $n$-fold relative Verschiebung homomorphism $V_{A^t/K,n}:(A^t)^{(p^n)} \rightarrow A^t$. (The Verscheibung homomorphism is defined rather generally for commutative flat group schemes in section 4.2 of Exp. VII$_{\rm{A}}$ of SGA3, and it is dual to the $n$-fold relative Frobenius isogeny by applying 4.3.3 of loc. cit. on $p^m$-torsion for all $m \ge 0$, or cheat and *define* it to be the dual of that Frobenius isogeny.)  So you could ask if this "norm" is Tate-dual to the $L/K$-restriction map in degree-1 Galois cohomology.

The restriction ${\rm{H}}^1(K,A) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(L,A) \simeq {\rm{H}}^1(K,A^{(p^n)})$ is likewise identified with ${\rm{H}}^1(F_{A/K,n})$. Thus, since $V_{A/K,n}$ is dual to $F_{A/K,n}$, the elementary functoriality of the Tate pairing applied to the $K$-homomorphism $F_{A/K,n}$ reduces the observation that that the Tate pairing for $A_{K^{1/p}}$ over $K^{1/p}$ is equal to that of $A^{(p)}$ over $K$ via the isomorphism $K^{1/p} \simeq K$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I'll check the details. I did assume though that the extension is separable by saying that $L/K$ is Galois. Also, couldn't one check the compatibility of Weil restriction with duals by exploiting the compatibility of Weil restriction with base change to reduce to the compatibility of duals and products (to me this seems simpler than using the "norm of the Poincare bundle")?

Comment: The bit of "diagram chasing" that you mention ultimately reduces to showing that under the $\mathrm{Ext}^1$ point of view on the dual, the bijection $A^t(L) = B^t(K)$ is given by the composition $\mathrm{Ext}^1_L(A, \mathbb{G}_m) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{R}_{L/K}} \mathrm{Ext}^1_K(B, \mathrm{R}_{L/K}\mathbb{G}_m) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{Ext}^1_K(B, \mathrm{norm})} \mathrm{Ext}^1_K(B, \mathbb{G}_m)$. Would you be willing to indicate why $A^t(L) = B^t(K)$ identifies like this?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't see "Galois" in the question; anyway, you definitely don't want to restrict to just the Galois case in practice.  The proof of compatibility of dual with Weil restriction cannot be checked after base change unless you first *define over $K$* the compatibility map that you intend to prove is an isomorphism.  That is why I described it in terms which make sense directly over the ground field; of course, once the map is defined, to actually *prove* it is an isomorphism we make base change to split things and pass to the product situation that you suggested to think about.

Comment: To answer your question about the "bit of diagram chasing"...this is exactly due to the mechanism by which I *defined* (over $K$!!) how to identify ${\rm{R}}_{L/K}(A_L)^t$ with ${\rm{R}}_{L/K}(A^t_L)$.  So I suggest making sure you agree with my proposed specific mechanism to *define* how duality commutes with Weil restriction (which I guess from your first comment you tried to ignore), and then you should see that this implies the affirmative answer to the question in your second comment.

Comment: It seems that the proof of the $p$-part of Tate's theorem in characteristic $p > 0$ in Ch. III of Milne's "Arithmetic duality theorems" rest on the compatibility that you asked about (in the special case $L/K$ Galois cyclic); look at the middle square in the displayed diagram in the proof of Lemma 7.9 of Ch. III (whose commutativity does not seem to be addressed there, but perhaps either Milne discusses it elsewhere in the book or there is a simpler argument in the Galois case than the one I give for the separable case).

Comment: I agree about Galois vs. separable (I restricted to Galois for simplicity). Thanks for your insightful comment about duality and Weil restriction; I will clarify to myself your definition of the map. As for Milne's book, this is one of the many diagrams in his book whose commutativity is not proved. It seems to me that sometimes the commutativity of the diagrams that Milne is basing his arguments on are actually _difficult_ to prove: e.g., why does the first one in the pf. of III.7.8 commute (it is supposed to follow from III.C.5 which is not proved either)?

Comment: I think that under interpreting $\mathrm{Pic}^0$ as those $\mathbb{G}_m$-torsors that come from group extensions, your definition of the map simply corresponds to taking $\mathrm{Ext}^1(B, \mathrm{norm})$ as in my second comment. Then, for the compatibility of the dual with restriction of scalars, the eventual input (after base change to $K^s$) is that the Poincare bundle of a product of abelian varieties is the external product of Poincare bundles of the factors.

Comment: @QuestionMark: Yes, I completely agree with your preceding comment.  But the Tate pairing doesn't need biextensions for its definition, nor did I intend for it to be defined that way: given an extension of $K$-groups $1 \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m \rightarrow E \rightarrow A \rightarrow 1$ we get a connecting map ${\rm{H}}^1(K,A) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^2(K,\mathbf{G}_m)$ that I would say is the Tate pairing.  This ties in well with another description via composition of maps in the derived category of abelian sheaves on the fppf or etale sites on the category of $K$-schemes locally of finite type.

Comment: Concerning the first diagram in the proof of III.7.8 in Milne's book, I remember thinking about it a long time ago, but I'd have to refresh my memory about the details. The equality between my proposed definition and the bi-extension definition also requires some thought.  I'll try to come back to this a bit later.

Comment: That is a nice way to define the pairing and works for every $K$. It is a pity though that there doesn't seem to be a reference that would prove Tate local duality for abelian varieties for all $K$ at once using this definition. I am very interested in any comments on the diagram in III.7.8.

Comment: @QuestionMark:  In SGA7 there is a discussion about the relationship between the biextension map and Cartier duality at finite level, and I expect that if one unpacks what is going on in there then it will provide a proof that the first diagram in the proof of III.7.8 in Milne's book commutes and that my proposed definition of the Tate pairing agrees with the biextension definition.  However, I have never read that part of SGA7 carefully, so I cannot say anything more definite concerning that possible resolution to the uncertainty.  I am busy these days, but will try to think about it later.

Comment: For any scheme $S$ and abelian $S$-scheme $A$ with dual $B$, the Tate pairing $B(S)\times{\rm{H}}^1(S,A) \rightarrow{\rm{H}}^2(S,\mathbf{G}_m)$ (fppf abelian sheaves on the category of lfp $S$-schemes) via my proposed method agrees (up to a universal sign) with the one via biextensions. Indeed, by design composing the bi-extension morphism $A \otimes^{\mathbf{L}} B \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m[1]$ with $b:\mathbf{Z}_S \rightarrow B$ gives the mapping cone $f:A\rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m[1]$ for the $S$-group extension associated to $b\in B(S)={\rm{Ext}}^1_S(A,\mathbf{G}_m)$. Composing $f[1]$ with...

Comment: $\xi:\mathbf{Z}_S \rightarrow A[1]$ corresponding to a class in ${\rm{H}}^1(S,A)$ gives $\mathbf{Z}_S \rightarrow \mathbf{G}_m[2]$ that "is" the bi-extension method (up to a sign: careful with $f[1]$!). But connecting homomorphisms are induced by the *negative* of the mapping cone morphism, so my proposed method via connecting homomorphism applies to the extension of $A$ corresponding to $f$ really does give the same up to universal signs. Good luck sorting out the signs (also relevant if you compute another way by passing translation through left or right side of a derived tensor product).

Comment: So the upshot is that my answer does prove as well that the bi-extension method has the same functorial property which you wanted (up to sorting out the sign issues, which doesn't affect whether or not the pairing is perfect, so it is legitimate to now use this functorial property in a proof of perfectness, as Milne's book does for the $p$-part in characteristic $p$).

Comment: My guess was right about the relevance of SGA7 (Exp. VIII) to prove commutativity of III.7.8 in Milne's book, and fortunately one needs only Prop. 3.3.1 (whose proof is very cool).  It is a general compatibility of pairings in cohomology over any base scheme $S$  (pairings valued in ${\rm{H}}^2(S,\mathbf{G}_m)$, always using the result from section 11 of Brauer III that for coefficients in a smooth group scheme etale and fppf abelian cohomology coincide, so in char. $p$ we do not lose contact with Galois cohomology when using fppf methods). If you make it an MO question then I'll answer it.

Comment: Thanks for very helpful comments! I have made a question about III.7.8 here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177361/why-is-the-tate-local-duality-biextension-pairing-compatible-with-the-cartier-du

Answer (score 2):

If $m$ is an integer coprime to the characteristic of $k$, then the pairing between $A^t(K)/m A^t(K)$ and the $m$-torsion part of $H^1(K,A)$ is compatible with the cup pairing 
$$H^1(K,A^t[m]) \times H^1(K,A[m]) \to H^2(K,\mu[m])\cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$$
through the short exact sequences from Kummer theory
$$ 0\to A(K)/mA(K) \to H^1(K,A[m])\to H^1(K,A)[m]\to 0$$
and likewise for $A^t$.
Now, for the local duality in $H^1$, the dual map to restriction is corestriction, because of the formula $\xi\cup\operatorname{cor}(\eta) = \operatorname{cor}(\operatorname{res}(\xi)\cup\eta)$ and the compatibility of the Hasse invariant with the corestriction in $H^2$.

That is a sketch how to prove it for the prime-to-characteristic part. The original [paper](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/SB/SB_1956-1958__4_/SB_1956-1958__4__265_0/SB_1956-1958__4__265_0.pdf) by Tate already made use of this in the proof.

Comment: The above before the mention of corestriction works as written even if $m > 0$ is divisible by the characteristic (using fppf cohomology and fppf Kummer sequence), so it seems the merit of Galois cohomology (which needs $m$ not divisible by the characteristic) vs. fppf cohomology is the availability of corestriction (which ultimately expresses exactness of finite etale pushforward for the etale topology, whereas finite flat pushforward is not fppf exact) and "norm".

Comment: Thanks for your response, Chris! You base your argument on the compatibility that I have alluded to in my previous comment: it would be helpful if you could indicate how to prove this compatibility (I am aware that people take this for granted)? Note that in characteristic $p$ the "biextension definition" of the pairing has to be used (in place of augmented cup products), so checking the compatibility involves dealing with edge maps in some spectral sequences, which is what makes this checking difficult for me. Any comments you may have on this would be most helpful.

Comment: It was not clear to me what definition of the pairing you are using. I thought you refer to the original definition by Tate (which is away from the characteristic). The compatibility between the two pairings is given in Proposition 2.1 in https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~taf1000/papers/ctpair.html by Tom Fisher (and probably in many other places).

Comment: I wouldn't know a good reference for the comparison with the bi-extension pairing. Maybe Milne's Airhtmetic Dualities ?

Comment: As far as I know, Milne's book doesn't discuss the comparison of pairings: it proves the duality in characteristic $0$ using one definition of the pairing and in characteristic $p$ using a completely different definition (based on biextensions, which is the correct definition, i.e., works regardless of the characteristic). I don't know of a reference for compatibility between the two pairings. The Fisher reference is written only for elliptic curves and uses the definition of the pairing that does not seem suitable in characteristic $p$; I therefore doubt that it resolves the question at hand.

Comment: @user52824: do you have an example of a nonexact finite flat pushforward?

Comment: Maybe you want to edit the question. It seems to me that the question you wanted to ask could be made more precise.

Comment: @QuestionMark:  Sure, just let $k'/k$ be a purely inseparable extension of degree $p$ in characteristic $p$, and apply ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}$ to the $p$-torsion Kummer sequence over $k'$.  Letting $f:{\rm{Spec}}(k') \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(k)$ be the finite flat structure map, you get that $f_{\ast}(\mathbf{G}_m)$ is "${k'}^{\times}$ as a $k$-group", and in particular $p$-power on this $p$-dimensional smooth commutative affine group is valued in its 1-dimensional maximal $k$-torus (modulo which it becomes $p$-torsion, hence unipotent).  In particular, $f_{\ast}$ applied to $p$-power isn't onto.

Comment: @QuestionMark: Another striking example (again expressing the initially disorienting fact that $f_{\ast}(\mu_p) = {\rm{R}}_{k'/k}(\mu_p)$ has dimension $p-1>0$ in the preceding comment), with $k'/k$ as in the preceding comment, is that applying ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}$ to the central $k'$-isogeny ${\rm{SL}}_p \rightarrow {\rm{PGL}}_p$ yields a *non-surjective* $k$-homomorphism with normal image having commutative cokernel representing the fppf higher direct image ${\rm{R}}^1 f_{\ast}(\mu_p)$.